# Bootstrap dialog box is disable

Tags: bootstrap-dialog

I am using MVC with angularjs and developing SPA. I am using the following code of bootstrap's dialog box, which is opening by hitting a button from a cshtml page. Code works well, but full screen turn to grey(disabled) including dialog box.

```
    <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-info btn-block"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#confirmModel">
<section>
    <div id="confirmModel" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModel" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    //Your content
                 </div>
            <div>
     </div>
</div>
```